# sql variable query in java

Tags: java, sql, swing, variables, combobox

I have 3 comboboxes in Java which are ;

'`departurecities={city1,city2,city3}
destinationcities={city1,city2,city3}
date={1,2,3,4,5,6...}`

I want to define a variable for the date because I don't know, what user will bus date, so I need a variable for SQL query.

I want to query like that:

`sql=select busid from buses where dep='city1'and des='city2' and
datebus=(????variable????);`

how can I define it ???

Please help me ..

Thanks in advance

Comment: I did not understand your question. Can you rephrase it?

Answer (score 1):

## `PreparedStatement`

In case you want to pass a variable to your SQL statement, I would recommend a [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html). See [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

You can use `setInt` in order to pass an integer, `setString` to pass a String etc. 
[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) is the API.

Here is an example:

```
String result = null;
String query = "select busid from buses where dep='city1'and des='city2' and datebus=?";
try {
    PreparedStatement preps = con.prepareStatement(query);
    preps.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt((String) date.getSelectedItem()));
    preps.execute();
    rs = preps.getResultSet();
    if (rs.next()) {
        result = rs.getString(...);
    }
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

I assume that ***datebus*** is declared as an integer in your database table.

Comment: No, you don't *need* a prepared statement.  But yes, I would *recommend* a prepared statement.  I think the OP's question is even more fundamental: "how do I declare a Java variable that's compatible with a SQL query?"

Comment: Thank you! I would recommend a prepared statement is correct.

Comment: An extra benefit of a prepared statement is eliminating risk of [*SQL Injection*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a String type for a constant like '2012-12-31 12:00 am', or, [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) or [GregorianCalendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) if you want to manipulate days/date differences in Java.

Comment: i want to define variable for date like , m=date.getSelectedItem()

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, you can convert string or character values into SQL's internal date format with the [to_date()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/functions203.htm) function:

SQL examples:

```
to_date('29-Oct-09', 'DD-Mon-YY')
to_date('10/29/09', 'MM/DD/YY')
to_date('120109', 'MMDDYY')
```

So, if you wanted to create a SQL command from Java:

```
String date = "12/31/2012";
String dep = "city1";
String des = "city2";
String SQL = "INSERT INTO buses VALUES(" + dep + "," + des + ",to_date(" + date + ",'MM/DD/YYYY'));";
```

Comment: Just make sure when you create your table to make the parameter of type DATE.